# Displaying login screen on x-screen 1

Tags: 20.04, xorg, login

I am working on a system (Ubuntu 20.04) configured with multiple x-screens.
Currently the login screen and desktop are displayed on x-screen 0
Is it possible to change the x-screen on which the login screen is displayed to something other then x-screen 0?

Comment: Could this help https://albertomatus.com/changing-login-display-in-ubuntu-20-04/ ?

Comment: This explains a setup having 3 displays on a single x-screen. In my case I have 3 displays where each is on its own x-screen. The Settings->Displays dialog in my case only shows the display on x-screen 0.